# p:selectOneMenu not keeping value after form validation

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu, selectedvalue

I want to keep selected values after form validation. My code is here:

```
    <h:form id="advanceSearchForm">
    <p:dataGrid value="#{advancedSearchBean.selectedCriteriasList}" id="advancedSearchGrid" var="criteria" rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
        columns="2" layout="grid" paginator="false" >
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" id="criteriaPanel">
            <p:panel id="criteria">
                <div>

                    <!-- select criteria -->
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{criteria}" label="#{criteria.name}" 
                            valueChangeListener="#{advancedSearchBean.addNewCriteria}"
                            converter="#{advancedSearchBean.criteriaConverter}">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{advancedSearchBean.criterias}"
                                    var="crt"
                                    itemLabel="#{crt.name}"
                                    itemValue="#{crt}"
                                    itemDisabled="#{advancedSearchBean.disableItem(crt.id)}" />
                                <f:ajax execute="@this"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <!-- launch date -->
                    <p:outputPanel rendered="#{criteria.id != null and (criteria.id == BusinessConstants.ADVANCED_SEARCH_FILTER_LAUNCH_DATE_ID)}">
                            <p:outputPanel>
                                <h:outputText value="From" styleClass="passportLabel" />
                                <p:inputMask required="true" id="launchStartDate" value="#{advancedSearchBean.launchStartDate}" mask="99/9999">
                                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/yyyy" timeZone="#{sessionScope.identity.timezone}" />
                                    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{advancedSearchBean.changeLaunchStartDate()}" />
                                </p:inputMask>
                            </p:outputPanel>
                            <p:outputPanel>
                                <h:outputText value="To" styleClass="passportLabel" />
                                <p:inputMask required="true" id="launchEndDate" value="#{advancedSearchBean.launchEndDate}" mask="99/9999">
                                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/yyyy" timeZone="#{sessionScope.identity.timezone}" />
                                    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{advancedSearchBean.changeLaunchEndDate()}" />
                                </p:inputMask>
                            </p:outputPanel>
                    </p:outputPanel>


                </div>
            </p:panel>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dataGrid>

    <!--  run search button -->
    <div>
        <p:commandButton id="runAdvancedSearch" value="Run search" action="#{advancedSearchBean.doAdvancedSearch}"
             update="advanceSearchForm:advancedSearchGrid"/>
    </div>
    </h:form>
```

When i'm typing a wrong date and click on the Search button, i'm getting my validation error message, and i'm also losing the selected value in the selectOneMenu.

The strange thing is that if redirect to another page and after that i'm coming back, it works... My bean is:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "advancedSearchBean")
@ViewScoped
public class AdvancedSearchBean {

private Map<Long, String> criteriaMap;
private List<AutocompleteCriteria> criterias;
private List<AutocompleteCriteria> selectedCriteriasList;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    criteriaMap = BusinessConstants.ADVANCED_SEARCH_CRITERIA.entrySet().stream().sorted(Entry.comparingByValue()).
            collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
    criterias = new ArrayList<AutocompleteCriteria>();
    for(Iterator<Map.Entry<Long, String>>it = criteriaMap.entrySet().iterator();it.hasNext();){
         Map.Entry<Long, String> entry = it.next();
         criterias.add(new AutocompleteCriteria(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }
    criteriaConverter = new AutocompleteConverter(criterias);
    selectedCriteriasList = new ArrayList<AutocompleteCriteria>();
    selectedCriteriasList.add(new AutocompleteCriteria(BusinessConstants.ADVANCED_SEARCH_FILTER_NO_CRITERIA, criteriaMap.get(BusinessConstants.ADVANCED_SEARCH_FILTER_NO_CRITERIA)));
}
```

Comment: So an h:selectOneMenu works? And if you want us to try to replicate, please post an [mcve]. See also [ask] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info on what info to provide as well.

Comment: h:selectOneMenu is not working either. I edited the code to be more simple to read, thanks

Comment: it is not about 'simple' it is about [mcve]

Comment: And please provide version info... as stated in the links

Comment: Let me guess, your bean is request scoped instead of view scoped?

Comment: No, my bean is @ViewScoped

Answer (score 0):

In your `p:selectOneMenu` You have `value="#{criteria}"` instead of `value="#{advancedSearchBean.criteria}"`.

Comment: criteria is the variable from the datagrid that has value="#{advancedSearchBean.selectedCriteriasList}" and var="criteria"